# trying to create a leaderboard for my program in python

Tags: python, leaderboard

I am working on an assignment, the goal is this...
create a program for a school tournament where participants can enter a tournament, then points are alocated to the team based on where they place in the event. there will be events such as (dodgeball, football, math, english) but i will work on these at a later date

at the moment i am trying to construct some code that will asign a point to a team, which is working. and then print the leaderboard(list of teams) this does not work

the leaderboard() function is not working and i do not know why not, please help me

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, num, name, size, score):
        self.num = num
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.score = score

    def add_victory(self):
        self.score += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team Number: {self.num} |-| Team Name: {self.name} |-| Member Count: {self.size} |-| Team Score: {self.score}'

def NewTournament():
    teams = []

    TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

    print('')
    for i in range(TeamCounter):
        NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
        MemberCount=int(input('How Many Members in Team? '))
        print('')
        teams.append( Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount, 0) )


def Score(teams):
    winner = input('Which Team Won the Event? ')
    for team in teams:
        if team.name == winner:
            team.add_victory()
            break
            print('Updated Leaderboard')

def Leaderboard():
    for t in teams: #does not work, does nothing
        print(t)
    
def Menu():
    MenuLoop=1
    while MenuLoop==1:
        print('1.Create Tournament')
        print('2.Update Existing Tournament')
        print('3.View Leaderboard')
        print('4.Exit')
        MenuOption=input('')
        if MenuOption=='1':
            print('Creating Tournament')
            NewTournament()#runs the new tournament function
            MenuLoop-=1
            Menu()
        elif MenuOption=='2':
            print('Updating Tournament')
            MenuLoop-=1
            EventName=input('Which Event Was Completed? ')
            winner=input('Which Team Won the Event? ')
            print('Event Winner:', winner, '||', 'Event:',EventName)
            print('Is this correct? Y/N')
            Check=input('')
            if Check=='y':
                print('Updating Leaderboard')
                Score(teams)
                Menu()
                    
                
                
        elif MenuOption=='3':
            MenuLoop-=1
            Leaderboard()
                
        elif MenuOption=='4':
            print('Exiting Program...')
        else:
            print('Error, please choose an option from the list below.')#keeps looping if user is not choosing a correct number from list


#start of program
teams = []        

print('░██╗░░░░░░░██╗███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░░█████╗░███╗░░░███╗███████╗')
print('░██║░░██╗░░██║██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░████║██╔════╝')
print('░╚██╗████╗██╔╝█████╗░░██║░░░░░██║░░╚═╝██║░░██║██╔████╔██║█████╗░░')
print('░░████╔═████║░██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██║░░██╗██║░░██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══╝░░')
print('░░╚██╔╝░╚██╔╝░███████╗███████╗╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░╚═╝░██║███████╗')
print('░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚══════╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚══════╝')#welcome user
print('')
Username=input('Enter Username: ')
Password=input('Enter Password: ')
if Username =='Admin' and Password == 'Admin':#very basic login system for security of school
    print('Logging in...')
    print('User Verified')
    Menu()
else:
    print('User Does Not Exist.')#stops pupils gaining unauthorised access
```

please understand i am still very new to python so the layout may be a mess or complicated or may not even make any sense to you, i am trying to make sense of it for you

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: nothing happens, it ends the program. i am expecting it to print all teams with their score s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from how you are storing your teams. At the bottom you initialize global `teams` list as `teams = []`. Then later in `NewTournament`  you create a new `teams` list which clashes with the global one:

```py
def NewTournament():
    teams = []

    TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

    print('')
    for i in range(TeamCounter):
        NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
        MemberCount=int(input('How Many Members in Team? '))
        print('')
        teams.append( Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount, 0) )
```

Because of this when you append the new `Team` to `teams` the change does not change the global `teams` which you use when listing the leader board. The simplest solution is to just remove the local `teams` variable:

```py
def NewTournament():
    TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

    print('')
    for i in range(TeamCounter):
        NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
        MemberCount=int(input('How Many Members in Team? '))
        print('')
        teams.append( Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount, 0) )/
```

A better fix would be to create a new `Tournament` class which can store the state of the tournament (the list of teams) more clearly, and remove your need to have top level methods which rely on global variables which is rarely a great idea.